# Keyboard Shortcut to Switch from a Full-screen Remote Desktop Session to your Local Machine?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

Is there a way, using the keyboard, to switch from a full-screen Remote Desktop session back to your host OS?

Answer (score 3):

This is what works for me in Windows 10 22H2, first press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Home</kbd>  which will move the focus to the Remote Desktop connection bar, then you can either press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  as if you were switching to another application, or you could use the alternative shortcut  <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>M</kbd>  to minimize the RDP application's window.